# PCA forth and back mean subtraction/addition

Tags: pca

**Bottom line question**: When I use my computed PCA projection matrix ***P*** to project a vector ***v*** into the other space (possibly lower in terms of dimensions), should I first **subtract** from ***v*** the mean of the vectors that were used for creating the covariance matrix that its principal eigenvectors form the projection matrix ***P*** ?

**Another derived question**: If the answer for the upper question is "correct", then when I project a "reduced" vector back to the original space, should I finally **add** to it the same mean?

Now the detailed question, including the steps that may cause a confusion:

PCA flow goes in the following way:

1. Taking ***m*** vectors of length ***d*** and computing their covariance matrix. Since the element in the ***(i,j)*** position is the covariance of the ***i***'th dimension and the ***j***'th dimension along all the ***m*** vectors, we can get the target ***(dxd)*** sized covariance matrix by subtracting the mean from all the vectors, creating a matrix ***A*** of size ***(dxm)***, in which all the mean-subtracted vectors are placed as column vectors and computing the multiplication: ***C = AA'***.
2. Computing the ***d*** eigenvalues and eigenvectors of ***C***, and for some pre-selected ***k***, creating a matrix ***P*** of size ***(kxd)***, and placing the ***k*** eigenvectors corresponding to the largest eigenvalues in descending order, as row vectors of ***P***.
3. For any vector ***v*** of the original dimension ***d***, that we want to project to the possibly reduced dimension ***k***, we compute the multiplication: ***u = Pv***, which produces a vector in the possibly reduced dimension ***k***.
4. For any vector ***u*** that was already projected to the possibly reduced dimension ***k***, if we want to project it back (after possible loss of data) to the original dimension ***d***, we compute the multiplication: ***v = P'u***, which produces a vector in the original dimension ***d***.

The question is whether:

- in step **(3)**, we should first subtract from ***v*** the mean we computed in step **(1)**?
- in step **(4)**, we should finally add to ***v*** the mean we computed in step **(1)**?

Comment: In step 1 you forgot to divide **AA'** by **m**.

Comment: I agree, but it is just a constant, it should not affect the eigenvectors and the order of their corresponding eigenvalues

Comment: Moreover, I think you should divide by **sqrt(m)**, like in the covariance measure formula

Comment: No, I believe it's **m**, unless you are re-scaling the samples themselves, in which case it's **sqrt(m)**. For PCA compession it indeed doesn't matter, as eigenvalues are only used to sort eigenvectors, which are unaffected by this constant factor.

Comment: You were right, it's **m**, not **sqrt(m)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer in some tutorials. Sharing it here so anyone can enjoy...

According to [this](http://faculty.iiit.ac.in/~mkrishna/PrincipalComponents.pdf) very nice and friendly PCA tutorial, the mean should indeed be subtracted in **(3)** and added in **(4)**. It also appears to be described in the same way in the very famous and classic [eigenfaces](http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/PCA/jcn.pdf) paper.

Here are some screenshots from the PCA tutorial, that make sense:

Projecting to new space:
  [image: Projecting to new space]

Projecting back to original space:
  [image: Projecting back to original space]

Answer (score 2):

> - in step (3), we should first subtract from v the mean we computed in step (1)?
> - in step (4), we should finally add to v the mean we computed in step (1)?

Yes and yes.

Also note that you can compute the covariance matrix in one pass over the samples if necessary, with:

```
COV = E[vv'] - E[v]E[v]'
```